# Hibernate: SQL error 8152 - String or binary data would be truncated

Tags: java, hibernate, truncate

I am using Hibernate with MS SQL Server. When I try to store my entity bean, I keep getting: "SQL error 8152 sqlstate 22001" and "String or binary data would be truncated".

I haven't found this issue anywhere.

Answer (score 7):

I finally solved it and wanted to share the solution here, in case anybody else has the same issue.

Normally this this occurs if a column is defined too small (like trying to store a string with 300 characters in a column defined as *varchar(256)*). But in my case it was different:

**Solution:** When I defined the table with annotations in hibernate, I defined a link to another table wrongly.

*Instead of defining it as many-to-one:*

```
@ManyToOne
public myEntity getMyEntity() {
  return myEntity;
}
```

*I defined it as a normal column:*

```
@Column
public myEntity getMyEntity() {
  return myEntity;
}
```

Maybe this helps anybody else.

Comment: This has saved me tons of time.

Answer (score 2):

The cause of this, for me, was trying to put something **too big** into a **column** that **can't fit it**.

I thought the problem might be something else—nope—I was just checking the **wrong column**.

My advice is to

1. Find an example that throws the error
2. Go through and **check the length** of each of your columns against your example.

Comment: For me, I changed varchar(256) to text and solved problem.